# Highcharts tickAmount off by 1

Tags: highcharts

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xptzq27r/1/

**Problem**: tickAmount is set to 3 and displays only 2 (Enter any value, actually displayed is that -1) Why?

```
chart: {
    tickAmount: 3,
}
```

Doc: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.tickAmount

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable `showLastLabel` option:

```
"yAxis": [{
    "opposite": false
}, {
    showLastLabel: true,
    tickAmount: 3,
    ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o7wgtsxa/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.showLastLabel